# difference between MDM certificate and APNS certificate

Tags: certificate, ios

I am new to mobile device management(MDM).I want to configure my own MDM Server to support iOS devices for mobile device management.

I know that for this apple developer Enterprise account is required and I know how to generate APNS ceritificate to support push notification.

But I want to know can I use one common certificate for MDM and APNS both or I need two get two seperate certificates as MDM certificate and APNS certificate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think APNS certificate is used for iOS MDM services per organization.
Please go through how to generate MDM certificate or APNS certificate for iOS MDM service.

For example [airwatch](https://web.archive.org/web/20120915045045/http://www.air-watch.com/downloads/GenerateAPNsCertificate.pdf) ,[mcafee](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB73382), [good-sales](http://%E2%80%A2%09http://good-sales.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/622/%7E/steps-for-generating-an-apns-mdm-certificate) and so on...